# Generate all partitions of a set of items

Tags: javascript, performance, array, ecmascript-6

Here are the items:

```
    var item = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

Desired output:

```
    [
        [ ['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'] ],
        [ ['a'],['b','c'],['d'] ],
        [ ['a'],['b'],['c','d'] ],
        [ ['a'],['b','c','d'] ],
        [ ['a'],['c'],['b','d'] ],....
    ]
```

The code:

```js
function getCombinations(items) {
   var res = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      for (var j = i + 1; j <= items.length; j++) {
         var temp = items.slice(i, j);
         var remained = items.slice(0, i).concat(items.slice(j, items.length));
         if (remained.length > 0) {
            var combinations = getCombinations(remained);
            combinations.forEach(combination => {
               res.push([temp].concat(combination));
            });
         } else {
            res.push([temp]);
         }
      }
    }
   return res;
}

var item = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

console.log(getCombinations(item));
```

Comment: You output for `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` doesn't contain `[['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd']]` which may be incorrect. Also, your output contain duplicate `[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']]`, `[['a'], ['b'], ['d'], ['c']]`.

Comment: The number of partitions is known as [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions), which may be quite large when there are more items in the input. As a result, any valid solution won't be much fast due to the fact of output size.

Answer (score 1):

I see the [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) tag added to this post. Did you intend to have answers address performance in terms of time, space or other aspects?

If you are looking to optimize performance in terms of time then I must restrain myself from suggesting changing the outer `for` loop to a `for of` loop. However I do see there is a `forEach` loop inside the nested `for` loop. If you really want to optimize for performance, then consider using a `for` loop instead of that `.forEach` method. Also consider whether the same result can be achieved by iterating backwards through the loops - this would allow for fewer operations<sup>[1](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-optimize-your-javascript-apps-using-loops-d5eade9ba89f/#optimizations)</sup>.

Given that an arrow function is used in the `.forEach()` callback, other [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features can be used - e.g. `const` and `let` instead of `var`, [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead of calling `.concat()`, etc.